# How to put a fancybox from a marker google maps v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map (v3) where I'm placing several bookmarks, and I want to be able to click bookmarks and extract a Fancybox iFrame. I tried but it doesn't work

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {lat: element.COOR_varCoordenadaLatitud, lng: element.COOR_varCoordenadaLongitud},
              map: map,
              icon: image,
              shape: shape,
              title: element.COOR_varNombre,
              zIndex: element.COOR_intId
              });
marker.addListener('click', function() {
              var src='http://localhost:8000/monumento/vistaindividual/13';
              $.fancybox.open({
                href: src,
                type: 'iframe',
                padding: 0
              });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the marker first then use this google maps object to add the event Click to your marker for example :

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:centerPosition,
    url: '/'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              var src='http://localhost:8000/monumento/vistaindividual/13';
              $.fancybox.open({
                href: src,
                type: 'iframe',
                padding: 0
              });
});
```

Comment: I did it, There is a part of how I call the fancybox